# Can I call update() directly on a record?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I retrieved a record like so:

```
$record = $collection->find(array(
      'name' => $name
      ));
```

Is there any way to update the record directly without having to requery the collection, or is it a shallow copy with no reference?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need
 [findAndModify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findandmodify.php)

The findAndModify command atomically modifies and returns a single document. By default, the returned document does not include the modifications made on the update. To return the document with the modifications made on the update,new option can be used.